# libx264 - Setting up AVCodecContext for HD & SD capturing

Tags: windows, visual-c++, libavcodec, libx264

I'm trying to configure the `AVCodecContext` properly in order to capture HD in real-time (1080i) and SD (720 x 576) - also interlaced. I'm using libx264 with the ffmpeg static lib on Windows OS.
If anybody can help with `flags`, `gop_size`, `max_b_frames` and all other AVCodecContext's members...

For example, I guess I should have `CODEC_FLAG_INTERLACED_ME | CODEC_FLAG_INTERLACED_DCT` flags set. However, what I need is the whole story on how to set all this up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming for real time encoding, just use:

```
x264_param_default_preset(&param, "ultrafast", "zerolatency");
```

This will set what you need.
You may want to set VBV parameters on top of this if you have bandwidth requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set any options unless you know they're already not right for you. libav 0.8 sets everything correctly by default.